# Python strip() method isn't working as expected

Tags: python

I have some lines of text that I want to remove all trailing characters from.

The lines are like this:

```
company-transit-hub4 ******
company-transit-hub3 (lab)
company-master
```

I want just the beginning of the line including dashes, for example: company-transit-hub4 or company-transit-hub3.

I'm reading from a csv file. This is what I'm doing in my code:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    print("in all csv reader")
    print(f"Row: {row}")
    time.sleep(30)
    aws_account = row[0]
    print(f"AWS Account before strip: {aws_account}")
    aws_account = aws_account.strip()
    print(f"AWS Account Strip: {aws_account.strip()}")
```

This is the output I get from my script:

```
AWS Account before strip: company-transit-hub4 ******
AWS Account Strip: company-transit-hub4 ******
```

The trailing characters can be almost anything because I'm reading from a very large file. I'm only using a few examples to keep it brief.

Why is the strip() method not removing the trailing characters in these cases?

Comment: So you want strip to remove all characters after (and including) the last ```space```?

Comment: Without arguments, `.strip()` strips leading/trailing whitespace

Comment: Yes I want to remove all characters after and including the last space.

Comment: For the **last** space: `aws_account.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]`.

Comment: `aws_account.rpartition(' ')[0]` runs in 2/3 of the time of `aws_account.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]` on my computer.  Of course it's a single line so it's a micro-optimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `str.split()` and then use index

**Ex:**

```
aws_account = aws_account.split()[0]
```

---

```
data = ['company-transit-hub4 ******', 'company-transit-hub3 (lab)', 'company-master']
for aws_account in data:
    print(aws_account.split()[0])
```

**Output:**

```
company-transit-hub4
company-transit-hub3
company-master
```

Comment: or `str.replace("the_string", "")`

Comment: @BlueRineS OP said `The trailing characters can be almost anything because I'm reading from a very large file`

Comment: Why does using the index make the difference?

Comment: @bluethundr Using `str.split()` will give you a list of elements that are space separated. Then you use index[0] to access the first element

Comment: `"for aws_account in data:aws_account.split()[0]"` 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.571 usec per loop. `"for aws_account in data:aws_account.partition(' ')[0]"` 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.415 usec per loop.  (Although I do admit splitting on any whitespace is different than splitting on a literal space.)